# Windows 8.1 Professional Hyper-V cannot boot up

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I am trying to install hyper-v on windows 8.1 professional to run Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator. But after enabling it from the optional features, my laptop restarts but does not boot up again!!

Please help me, I want to test my application as soon as possible but cannot since my phone has a damaged micro usb port, so cannot deploy to test it.

I have attached the system info.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeR5X.jpg

Comment: This is likely best answered on superuser.com. But, without more details, you're unlikely to get better assistance. How long are you waiting for the boot to occur the first time? Is anything shown on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons and solutions for this problem. One is mentioned [here](http://mou.me.uk/2012/08/27/windows-wont-boot-after-activating-hyper-v-in-windows-8/) - turning off USB 3.0 in BIOS and the other [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/Hyper-V-does-not-work-HP-Pavilion-15-e080sr/td-p/3594229) - updating BIOS